# Android fragments navigation, going back to a specific fragments in the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation, back-stack

In our personal API, we have the possibility to parse a folders tree (not the one in the device, but one we got from web service). So we are displaying each folder level and it's content in a Fragment. Then if the user select a folder, we are displaying the same fragment, with another content.
Let's call this fragment `BrowseFragment`.

We are trying to go back in the folders tree at a specific level. For example, from level 5 to level 2, and it does not work: sometimes got a blank screen, sometimes the wrong screen. However the backstack seems fine because when the user goes back to one level higher with android back button, everything is fine.

So here is our backstack after some clicks:

> browseFragment#1
>
> browseFragment#4
>
> browseFragment#14
>
> browseFragment#47
>
> browseFragment#72

Here is how we replace the fragment :

```
public void onSelectFolder(Folder folderSelected) {

    // Getting transaction
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    BrowseFragment browseFragment = new BrowseFragment();

    // Adding bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(Constants.FRAGMENT_ARG_BROWSED_FOLDER_TREE, (Serializable)this.foldersBrowsed);
    browseFragment.setArguments(bundle);

    // Replacing fragment
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, browseFragment, Constants.FRAGMENT_KEY_BROWSE + folderSelected.getIdFolder());
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_from_left);
    ft.addToBackStack(Constants.FRAGMENT_KEY_BROWSE + folderSelected.getIdFolder()); // Example: "browseFragment#1", "browseFragment#12" etc...
    ft.commit();
}
```

And here is how we are going back to a specific level:

```
public void onSelectFolderFromBreadCrumb(Folder folderSelected) {

    // Going back in the backstack
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(Constants.FRAGMENT_KEY_BROWSE + folderSelected.getIdFolder(), 0); // Example: "browseFragment#1", "browseFragment#12" etc...
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to start use Navigation Architecture Components. transactions are not good for complex usages like your app. You can check it from this url: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started -- if you can use it you can use it by two ways. First of all u can go specific fragment smoothly by setting parameters, second one it has no parameters. If you dont initialize parameter you go back last fragment!

Answer (score 0):

try this `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(Constants.FRAGMENT_KEY_BROWSE + folderSelected.getIdFolder(), POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`
I was having an issue like yours and managed to solve it after reading this
[blog post](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2017/12/18/fragmentback/)